# Firestore update document function call does not finish executing prior to redirecting the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update some data on Google firestore then redirect the client to another page, however the update({}) does not seem to finish before the redirect.

Here is the code that is causing my issue

```
Collection.doc(docId).update({
    usrToken: sessionStorage.getItem(0),
    usrExpiration: exprTime
}).then(ref => {
    window.location.href = './overview.html';
});
```

What is really strange is that if I comment `window.location.href = './overview.html` out, `.update()` works fine.
I also have a `.add()` function that uses nearly the same structure and works perfectly fine:

```
Collection.add({
    usrToken: sessionStorage.getItem(0),
    usrExpiration: authExpiration,
    usrPhotoUrl: user.photoURL,
    usrEmail: user.email,
    usrName: user.displayName,
    usrNickname: user.displayName
}).then(ref => {
    window.location.href = "./welcome.html";
});
```

Is there any way that I can force the `.update()` function to finish before the window is redirected?

--UPDATE--
Turns out that this issie is being caused by asyncronus operation in JavaScript. Is there a way to halt operation or execution of a line until all asyncronus calls have been finished?

--UPDATE--
This is now what my code looks like

```
updateTokenData(authExpiration, mateQuery, mateRef);
redirect('./overview.html');
```

So now my issue is simply: 
How do I force updateTokenData(...) to finish executing before redirect(...) starts excecuting?

Comment: Try enabling debugging to get more clues: `firebase.firestore.setLogLevel('debug');` and add the `catch` method, just in case.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. See my JSBin here: https://jsbin.com/fasenah/edit?html,js and the output page to test with here: https://jsbin.com/fasenah

Comment: I setup the debug log, when I include the redirect it stops at 
```@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.10.1) [MemoryPersistence]: Starting transaction: Get next mutation batch```

Comment: When I run without the redirect, the console has another 5 lines:
```@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.10.1) [Connection]: WebChannel transport closed
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.10.1) [PersistentStream]: stream callback skipped by getCloseGuardedDispatcher.
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.10.1) [Connection]: WebChannel sending: {"streamToken":"EAEZEGhCAoH0tbU=","writes":[]}
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.10.1) [Connection]: WebChannel transport closed
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.10.1) [PersistentStream]: stream callback skipped by getCloseGuardedDispatcher.```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem.  I discovered that I needed to use "return" in order for it to wait for the asynchronous update when redirecting.  I found it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) under the 'How Promises Work with Functions' section.

Using your code it would look like this:

```
return Collection.doc(docId).update({
    usrToken: sessionStorage.getItem(0),
    usrExpiration: exprTime
    }).then(() => {
    window.location.href = './overview.html';
    });
```